# Creating a closed task in APEX

Tags: tasks

I'm trying to create a "Log a Call" task with apex.
I need this task to be marked as Closed but when I try to set the IsClosed field to true I'm getting the "Field not writable" error.

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

There is a field called status in task. Setting this to the string 'Completed' solves the issue. No need to write this isClosed flag. This flag gets checked once task status is closed.

Comment: There is a small code sample towards the end of http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/08/transcribing-voice-messages-to-tasks-with-the-tropo-api.html that demonstrates the use of `Status = 'Completed'`.

Comment: @metadaddy Wow!that integration is awesome .I read the blog post amazing work.thanks!